# Best practices for pointer validation?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

So, when I discovered the `shared_ptr` class (and its `weak_ptr` brother), I loved it. But then, one of our guys said it was too heavy and expensive. So now we just have raw pointers hanging out, and a fairly heavy multithreaded pipeline. Because bugs, we have a number of crashes that can't be null-guarded, because the pointers aren't actually null (but they are garbage). I've thought of the following constructs:

```
template<class T>
class GoodPtr {
public:
    GoodPtr() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mux);
        goodPtrs.emplace((T*)this);
    }

    virtual ~GoodPtr() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mux);
        goodPtrs.erase((T*)this);
    }

    static bool isGoodPtr(T* ptr) {
        // would love to use shared_mutex, but apparently it's not in c++11, so...
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mux);
        return goodPtrs.find((T*)ptr) != goodPtrs.end();
    }

private:
    static std::unordered_set<T*> goodPtrs;
    static std::mutex mux;
};

template<class T> std::unordered_set<T*> GoodPtr<T>::goodPtrs;
template<class T> std::mutex GoodPtr<T>::mux;

template <class T>
class GoodPtrHolder {
public:
    GoodPtrHolder(){}
    GoodPtrHolder(T* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
    void setPtr(T* ptr) {
        _ptr = ptr;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        if (_ptr && GoodPtr<T>::isGoodPtr(_ptr)) {
            return _ptr;
        } else {
            static T dummy;
            return &dummy;
        }
    }

private:
    T* _ptr = nullptr;
};
```

Given the following example:

```
class testo : public GoodPtr<testo> {
public:
    testo() {}
    virtual ~testo(){}
    void doSomething() {
        printf("sup %d\n", x);
    }
    void setX(int val) { x = val; }

private:
    int x;
};
```

and:

```
auto *test = new testo;
GoodPtrHolder<testo> testHolder(test);
testHolder->setX(5);
testHolder->doSomething();
delete test;
testHolder->doSomething();
```

Is this better or worse than `shared_ptr`, considering I have to keep a static table of pointers? Is there a better approach to the problem?

Comment: "(and its weak_ptr brother)" forget about `weak_ptr`. There are `std::unique_ptr<>` and `shared_ptr<>`.

Comment: "But then, one of our guys said it was too heavy and expensive. So now we just have raw pointers hanging out," \*roflmao x 2\*

Comment: "But then, one of our guys said it was too heavy and expensive." Compared to what. A crashing program is even more expensive. Make it work using std::shared_ptr profile and only after profiling decide it is to heavy and optimize. A working program is worth a lot more and easier to reason about than a broken one that does not work.

Comment: i have huge amount of size and speed critical code that uses shared_ptr, tell your guy that he is incorrect . unique_ptr has not overhead at all, shard _ptr has a wee bit

Comment: notice that all your code does is create a wraper around a pointer (just like shared_ptr does), but without its correctness, documentation and features

Comment: I doubt what you have written is faster than a shared pointer. All your pointers are going through a central repository (requiring a lock). This all threads when using any pointer must compete for the lock.

Comment: Step 1: Make it work. Step 2: See if it meets the performance requirements. If yes, done. Else proceed. Step 3 profile it to determine locations of slowdowns. Step 4: modify code to reduce or eliminate largest reducible slowdown. Step 5: Goto step 1.

Comment: @Swordfish `unique_ptr` is `shared_ptr`s best friend, I would say. Those are cool too. @Martin York fair enough about the speed, I was more worried about the memory overhead (although I do have a set of every pointer in the system)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from everything else, your code has undefined behavior here:

```
delete test;
testHolder->doSomething();
// ends up here:
        if (_ptr && GoodPtr<T>::isGoodPtr(_ptr)) {
//          ^^^^
```

The problem is that `_ptr` is a copy of `test`, and deleting `test` invalidates the pointer value.

In C++98 `[expr.delete]` says:

> 4. The *cast-expression* in a *delete-expression* shall be evaluated exactly once. If the *delete-expression* calls the implementation deallocation function (3.7.3.2), and if the operand of the delete expression is not the null pointer constant, the deallocation function will deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer **thus rendering the pointer invalid**. [*Note:* the value of a pointer that refers to deallocated storage is indeterminate. ]

Or in [this C++11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), `[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]`:

> 4. If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value (4.10), the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, **rendering invalid all pointers referring to any part of the *deallocated storage***. The effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined.

(All emphasis mine.)

After `delete test`, just looking at the pointer value invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: "just looking at the pointer value invokes undefined behavior", I don't really see in your references where it says that. I suppose I could cast it to `(intptr_t)` though... it's just an optimization to see if it's unset before calling the second condition.

Comment: @ntourte "*The effect of using an invalid pointer value [...] is undefined*"

Comment: is checking it using it? Obviously `_ptr->doThing()` will crash, but `if(_ptr != nullptr)` shouldn't, I would hope

Comment: @ntourte It says "using", not "dereferencing". The situation is the same in C, by the way: `free(ptr)` makes the value of `ptr` indeterminate, and using an indeterminate value in an expression can cause undefined behavior.